# Extraer nada más los 4 primeros números de una cadena PHP

Tags: php

Lo siguiente me da como resultado: `6403.05198007322.2464182920.3067346286572.45...`

casi hasta el infinito.

No como hacer para que se expresen nada más los 4 primeros números.

**Ayuda.**

```
$coind = bitcoin;
$json = \file_get_contents( "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/{$coinId}" );
$coins = json_decode($json);
foreach ($coins as $bitcoin) {

$valor = $bitcoin->price_usd;

echo $valor;
```

Comment: eso es un resultado de una operacion matematica ?

Comment: @srJJ No exactamente. Estoy agarrando la cifra de una API, pero como son demasiados números lo que se expresan, no puede realizar ninguna operación matemática sin que me de INF, entonces, yo supongo que la solución es llevar la cifra a 4 números en vez de los cientos que tiene.

Answer (score 2):

Es un claro error de planteamiento. Las soluciones que te han dado, 
unas y otras, dan el resultado que buscas. Otra cosa es el mal uso 
que se le de a la respuesta de la *Api*, y por lógica, no se obtenga el 
resultado esperado, que es lo que veo que pasa aquí.

Solo dos detalles del ejemplo:

```
$coind = bitcoin;
        ^       ^ -> Aquí faltan las comillas a no ser que sea una constante.

$json = \file_get_contents("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/{$coinId}");
                                   Esta variable no está definida -> ^^^^^^^
```

La documentación de la *Api* muestra perfectamente los resultados que
se obtiene en distintos casos.

Si analizas la url que pones como ejemplo, no necesita pasar el resultado por un 
*foreach* para obtener el valor que buscas. Solo hay que configurar bien 
la llamada para obtener la respuesta deseada:

## Un solo resultado

Añadiendo el nombre de la moneda a la ruta de la api nos da un solo resultado. 
Si compruebas la respuesta correcta retorna esto:

```
// a las 13:47 del 12 de agosto de 2018
[
    {
        "id": "bitcoin", 
        "name": "Bitcoin", 
        "symbol": "BTC", 
        "rank": "1", 
        "price_usd": "6348.38593618", 
        "price_btc": "1.0", 
        "24h_volume_usd": "4005442650.23", 
        "market_cap_usd": "109225725838", 
        "available_supply": "17205275.0", 
        "total_supply": "17205275.0", 
        "max_supply": "21000000.0", 
        "percent_change_1h": "-0.24", 
        "percent_change_24h": "3.22", 
        "percent_change_7d": "-9.68", 
        "last_updated": "1534073430"
    }
]
```

Por lo que solo tenemos que acceder a la posición 0 del *array* para obtener el objeto.

```
$coinId   = "bitcoin";
$json     = file_get_contents("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/{$coinId}");   
$coins    = json_decode($json);
$priceUsd = $coins[0]->price_usd; # 6366.19182834
$strpos   = strpos($priceUsd, '.'); # 4
$price    = substr($priceUsd, 0, $strpos); # 6366
echo "{$coins[0]->name}: {$price}";
```

Esto nos devuelve:

> Bitcoin: 6366

**Sobre las funciones utilizadas**

La función [***strpos***](http://php.net/manual/es/function.strpos.php) encuentra la posición de la primera ocurrencia de un substring en un string.
*En nuestro caso nos retorna **4** buscando el punto `.` que separa los decimales.*

La función [***substr***](http://php.net/manual/es/function.substr.php) devuelve parte de una cadena.
*Al pasar el valor de strpos como segundo argumento nos devuelve los números que necesitamos indpendientemente de que cambie el valor de la moneda, ya sea, 4, 2 o 9. (Las monedas inferiores a 1 devolverá 0)*

## Mas resultados

Si no ponemos ningún *id* en la *url* de la *api*, nos devuelve todas las monedas que tienen datos 
(que es lo que está pasando actualmente).

```
[
    {
        "id": "bitcoin", 
        "name": "Bitcoin", 
        "symbol": "BTC", 
        "rank": "1", 
        "price_usd": "6352.91437166", 
        "price_btc": "1.0", 
        "24h_volume_usd": "4030213074.96", 
        "market_cap_usd": "109304032697", 
        "available_supply": "17205337.0", 
        "total_supply": "17205337.0", 
        "max_supply": "21000000.0", 
        "percent_change_1h": "0.02", 
        "percent_change_24h": "3.35", 
        "percent_change_7d": "-9.64", 
        "last_updated": "1534077331"
    }, 
    {
        "id": "ethereum", 
        "name": "Ethereum", 
        "symbol": "ETH", 
        "rank": "2", 
        "price_usd": "323.002420047", 
        "price_btc": "0.051031", 
        "24h_volume_usd": "1741303184.3", 
        "market_cap_usd": "32713168450.0", 
        "available_supply": "101278400.0", 
        "total_supply": "101278400.0", 
        "max_supply": null, 
        "percent_change_1h": "0.17", 
        "percent_change_24h": "3.05", 
        "percent_change_7d": "-20.68", 
        "last_updated": "1534077346"
    },
    //...
]
```

Y aquí es donde si se debe usar el *foreach* para obtener las distintas monedas y usar un formato adecuado para presentarlas.

```
$json   = file_get_contents("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/");
$coins  = json_decode($json);
foreach($coins as $coin) {
    $priceUsd = $coin->price_usd;
    $strpos   = strpos($priceUsd, '.');
    $price    =  substr($priceUsd, 0, $strpos);
    echo "{$coin->name}: {$price}; ";
}
```

Esto nos devuelve:

> Bitcoin: 6353; Ethereum: 323; XRP: 0; Bitcoin Cash: 574; EOS: 5; Stellar: 0; Litecoin: 60; Cardano: 0; Tether: 1; Monero: 95; IOTA: 0; TRON: 0; Ethereum Classic: 13; Dash: 167; NEO: 18; Binance Coin: 11; NEM: 0; Tezos: 1; Zcash: 159; OmiseGO: 4; VeChain: 0; 0x: 0; Qtum: 4; Lisk: 3; Decred: 41; Bitcoin Gold: 19; Bytecoin: 0; Maker: 478; BitShares: 0; DigiByte: 0; Zilliqa: 0; Dogecoin: 0; ICON: 0; Aeternity: 1; Steem: 0; MOAC: 3; Augur: 21; Ontology: 1; Basic Attention Token: 0; Siacoin: 0; Verge: 0; Bitcoin Diamond: 1; Waves: 1; Bytom: 0; Stratis: 1; RChain: 0; Golem: 0; Nano: 1; KuCoin Shares: 1; Pundi X: 0; Populous: 4; Hshare: 3; Status: 0; Mithril: 0; MaidSafeCoin: 0; Komodo: 1; IOST: 0; Metaverse ETP: 2; Dentacoin: 0; Ardor: 0; Mixin: 257; Huobi Token: 2; Waltonchain: 2; DigixDAO: 55; MonaCoin: 1; Kin: 0; Wanchain: 0; Aurora: 0; GXChain: 1; aelf: 0; Cryptonex: 2; ChainLink: 0; FunFair: 0; ZenCash: 19; Bancor: 1; Holo: 0; MCO: 5; Decentraland: 0; Emercoin: 1; Bitcoin Private: 3; Aion: 0; WAX: 0; Ark: 0; Nxt: 0; Power Ledger: 0; Dropil: 0; ReddCoin: 0; ZCoin: 12; Kyber Network: 0; Loopring: 0; PIVX: 1; Nebulas: 1; TenX: 0; Nuls: 1; TrueUSD: 1; CyberMiles: 0; Electroneum: 0; Iconomi: 0; Polymath: 0; Centrality: 0;

## Varios resultados entre todos

Y si quieres localizar varias entre todas, añades los *ids* en un array, un condicional y listo!

```
$coinIds = ["bitcoin", "ethereum"];
$json   = file_get_contents("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/");
$coins  = json_decode($json);
foreach($coins as $coin) {
    if(in_array($coin->id, $coinIds)) {
        $priceUsd = $coin->price_usd;
        $strpos   = strpos($priceUsd, '.');
        $price    =  substr($priceUsd, 0, $strpos);
        echo "{$coin->name}: {$price}; ";
    }
}
```

Esto nos devuelve:

> Bitcoin: 6353; Ethereum: 323;

Answer (score 0):

leyendo tu codigo llego a la conclusion que puedes implementar dos opciones, las cuales te ayudaran con tu problema:

```
$numero_api= 6403.05198007322.2464182920.3067346286572;
```

> Primera Forma:

```
//split divide la cade en el factor que desee convitiendo el recertor en un array
//en este caso no le ponemos factor para que en cada campo lo divida ''
$numeros = split('', $fecha);
//queda como un arreglo en el cual del 0 al 3 son los 4 primeros numeros
echo $numeros[0] // = 6
echo $numeros[1] // = 4
echo $numeros[2] // = 0
echo $numeros[3] // = 3
```

Aqui te dejo el link sobre [split()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.split.php)

> Segunda Forma:

```
//con el roun te trae los primeros numero antes de un (.)
//NOTA: si quiere decimales seria round($numero_api, cantidad) 
el segundo parametros le diras cuantos decimales puede traer
echo round($numero_api);
```

Aqui te dejo el link sobre [Round](http://php.net/manual/es/function.round.php)

Espero te sirva y la marques xD, me comentas que tal te fue... **ReNiceCode...**

Comment: Jejeje, hermano, gracias, pero, no funcionan. T_T

Comment: que te sale ? usando el split y que te salen en el round ?

Comment: Con round se alarga la cifra, jajajaja, es curioso, y con split da error.

Comment: que erro da el split? edita la pregunta y muestra el como lo estas implementando

Answer (score 0):

Con substr puedes --> http://php.net/manual/es/function.substr.php

```
<?php
$cadenadetexto="6403.05198007322.2464182920.3067346286572.45";
$cuatro_primeros = substr($cadenadetexto, 0,4 );   
echo $cuatro_primeros;
?>
```

Ojala te ayude.

Comment: Hola, da 64036403640364036403, muchas veces.

Comment: es por tu foreach.

Comment: ¿En serio? Voy a intentarlo sin el.

Comment: si mira que el patron esta repitiendo solo las 4 primeras, entonces saca el roun del foreach

Comment: Bueno, será un lío pero, nada funciona, $bitcoin->price_usd no funciona sin el foreach, ya que agarra los datos de una API, y de paso, no es una cadena de texto, o no sé, porque no funciona con el "substr"

Comment: Muchas gracias a los dos, seguiré intentando. Si se les pasa una solución por la cabeza, los amare, jajaja.

Comment: se trata de un proceso de lógica, creo que deberías leer esto -->  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19758954/get-data-from-json-file-with-php/19758995

Comment: @AndrésNavarro edita tu pregunta y ponga los ejemplo que te emos dado, y asi sabremos el metodo que has implemetado y la forma

Answer (score 0):

Que tal si almacenas en un arreglo los resultados de tu objeto, lo mejor sería conocer la estructura de ese objeto para poder hacer un mejor diagnóstico y proponer un recorrido... pero, como a tí sólo te interesa un precio de entre toodas las propiedades del objeto, entonces, después de recorrer el objeto, el precio lo almacenas en otro arreglo y luego sólamente imprimes un indice de ese arreglo. No es una solución óptima, pero sería mejor, conocer la estructura de la variable `$json` o de la variable `$coins`.

```
    $coind = bitcoin;
    $json = \file_get_contents( "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/{$coinId}" );
    $coins = json_decode($json);
    $arr_precios = array();
    foreach ($coins as $bitcoin) {
        $arr_precios[] = intval(substr($bitcoin->price_usd,0,4));
    }
    echo($arr_precios[0]);
```